# Should I use backshift with both verbs in "Everyone thinks I am overreacting"?

Tags: indirect-speech, backshifting

Which one of the following clauses is better or could both be used when the original utterance is "Everyone thinks I am overreacting."

- "Jill said that everyone thought she was overreacting."
- "Jill said that everyone thinks she was overreacting."

Thank you already for your help!

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions already, so this may be a duplicate or near-duplicate. Generally, I would backshift. Sometimes you might not, if the thing is assumed to continue into the present (everyone still thinks she's overreacting), but as a rule of thumb for English learners, backshifting is safer: "Jill said that everyone thought she was overreacting." (You don't say if you are a learner, or have some specific reason for not backshifting.)

Comment: The two sentences mean different things. Only the first is the correct way of expressing the direct form.